# Move all .txt files from one folder to another folder using Node js

Tags: node.js, nodes

I have tried with this code but it's not working it display error like that file not exists on that directory.
 System take .txt as file not as extension of file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
    var oldPath = '/abc/def/ghi/*.txt'
    var newPath = '/xyz/cbi/'

    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
const shell = require('child_process').execSync ; 
const src= `/abc/def/ghi`;
const dist= `/xyz/cbi`;

shell(`mv ${src}/* ${dist}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem [Check here](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/copy.md)

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')

// With a callback:
fs.copy('/tmp/myfile', '/tmp/mynewfile', err => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  console.log('success!')
})
```

Comment: maybe using fs.move would be better (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move.md)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

For One File:

```
 const moveThem = async () => {
   // Move file ./js/foo.js to ./ns/qux.js
   const original = join(__dirname, 'js/foo.js');
   const target = join(__dirname, 'ns/qux.js'); 
   await mv(original, target);
 }
```

For Many Files:

```
 mv('source/dir', 'dest/a/b/c/dir', {mkdirp: true}, function(err) { 
 });
```

OR

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
 mv = spawn('mv', ['/dir1/dir2/*','dir1/']);
```

Comment: I have try your solution but this error display:mv(oldPath,newPath, {mkdirp: true}, function(err) {
^

ReferenceError: mv is not defined

Comment: use this also const {promisify} = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const {join} = require('path');
const mv = promisify(fs.rename);